# How to setup environment specific params for each environment in python

Tags: python

I am new to deploying python code that connects to databases up though our environments. How and where would I specify the database server and database info (or any environment specific info) for my application when it runs in our STAGE environment vs our PROD environment?

What is the best practice for doing this in a python application (the application isn't a web app or API app)?

The code is stored in a ADO repo and it has a build and release pipeline that pushes the code out to each VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to have several possible configurations depending on the deployment environment without having to rework the code. If this is the case :

I recommend you to look at the configparser library. It allows you to read a configuration file with different parameters.

You can have one configuration file per environment and put your parameters in it.

For example:
In your file database.cfg

```
[DATABASE]
DATABASE_TYPE=mysql
USERNAME=user
PASSWORD=Password
IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
PORT=3306
DATABASE_NAME=python
```

And in your python program

```py
import configparser
    
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("database.cfg")
username = config["DATABASE"]["USERNAME"]
```